# How do I put multiple unrelated folders into a Visual Studio Code workspace?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I have a tree of more than 100GB of sources I work in that looks like this:

> $/unrelated
>   $/tests/my-team/tests.config
>   $/tests/my-team/tests/test/test.cpp
>   $/tests/my-team/tests/test2/test.cpp
>   $/tests/unrelated
>   $/unrelated
>   $/product/my-team/product.config
>   $/product/my-team/foobar.h
>   $/product/my-team/foobar.cpp

My team only works with a very small subset of these. I would like Visual Studio Code to show only these:

> $/tests/my-team/*
>   $/product/my-team/*

and not index / search other directories. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think so. Maybe just create your own working set with a set of soft links.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `.vscode/settings.json` (File - Preferences - Workspace Settings) to your workspace and add:

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite default and user settings.
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/.git": true,
        "**/.DS_Store": true
        "unrelated/**" : true
    },
}
```

This will (I believe) also exclude from... but you can specify that directly

```
"search.exclude": {
    "**/node_modules": true,
    "**/bower_components": true,
    "unrelated/**" : true
},
```